Wait for API call to complete in Angular 14
In my Angular 14 application, I am making 2 API calls and then combine them using "combineLatest" from rxjs and then assigning the data to a variable.
I have to use that data/variable in a seperate function. How do I make sure that the second function ( seperate function ) is called only once the data/variable.
I understand that a simple solution will be to call the second function inside the "combineLatest" block but unfortunately I cannot do that. Is there a way to make sure that the second function is called only when the data is available.
Here is my sample code:
this.dataSubscription = combineLatest([aaaSubscription, bbbObservable]).subscribe(result => {
  this.someVariable = result[0];
} 

seperateFunction() {
  if(this.someVariable) {
    console.log("Do this")
  }


It's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. Why can't you just call this.separateFunction() inside the subscribe handler?

unfortunately, I cannot do that because of the complexity if the code, the block is called at other places where I cannot call this.seperateFunction()

The this.someVariable is assigned asynchronously inside an observable subscription. And you're attempting to use it synchronously somewhere else. It is not possible. Once a variable is async, all the workflows that depend on it must be async. You'd need to provide more context on when and where you wish to trigger the seperateFunction() function. Go through this post to learn more about async behaviour.

Maybe next one is the decision?
this.dataSubscription = 
  combineLatest([aaaSubscription,bbbObservable])
    .pipe(
      tap(result => this.someVariable = result[0])
    )
    .subscribe(result => {
      this.seperateFunction();
    }); 

seperateFunction() {
  if(this.someVariable) {
    console.log("Do this")
  }


You can use map , flatMap, switchMap
this.dataSubscription = combineLatest([aaaSubscription, bbbObservable]).switchMap((result) => {
    this.someVariable = result[0];
    this.seperateFunction();
    return of(result);
     }).subscribe(result => {
    // do whatever you want
} 

seperateFunction() {
  if(this.someVariable) {
    console.log("Do this")
  }


You can create an observable, for example, a Subject, and send some flag/data after your API call is done, then subscribe to that Subject and write your logic there.
something like this : StackBlitzLINK

Also, if you are not allowed to change inside the API call subscribe method, there is another workaround - create another component , make API's response as input to that component then you can get that data in onchanges method of that component everytime there is dat from API call. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-subject-observable-3sqqzf?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

RxJs has tons of operators and Angular has AsyncPipe so there is rarely any need to mix reactive and stateful data management. You can do everything declaratively. Side effects (such as logging to console or setting a state variable) should be done in a tap operator. There is really no reason to put anything in the body of subscribe.
someVariable$ = combineLatest([aaaSubscription, bbbObservable])
  .pipe(
    map(result => result[0]),
    tap(data => { if(data) console.log("Do this") })
  );

If you then have a binding for someVariable in your template, you would bind it with [bindingAttribute]="someVariable$ | async". Otherwise, subscribe to it in OnInit or AfterViewInit with a call to takeUntil that passes in an observable that fires and completes in OnDestroy:
stop$ = new Subject<any>();

ngOnInit() {
  this.someVariable$
    .pipe(
      takeUntil(this.stop$)
    ).subscribe();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.stop$.next(true);
  this.stop$.complete();
}

